# ubuntu 18.04 LTS, -bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ubuntu, limit

We are running a small rasa chatbot an a fresh ubuntu 18.04 installation with only a few extras (nginx, firefox, mysql). The setup is a vServer with 8GB mem, 4 cores and 100GB HD. 
Top and Htop show that all numbers are far below limits. Processes (set /proc/*/task/*/cwd/.; echo $#) show 197. (ulimit -u 62987). CPU runs below 10%, Mem is 90% free. However, we are constantly getting the -bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable error. 
It is unclear what limit we are hitting that results in this error - any idea is appreciated.

Thank you,
Uli

top - 07:49:19 up 1 day, 16:30,  1 user,  load average: 0,00, 0,29, 0,79

Tasks:  89 gesamt,   1 laufend,  71 schlafend,   0 gestoppt,  17 Zombie

%CPU(s):  0,2 be,  0,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 99,7 un,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st

KiB Spch :  8388608 gesamt,  7315224 frei,   854700 belegt,   218684 Puff/Cache

KiB Swap:        0 gesamt,        0 frei,        0 belegt.  7519940 verfü Spch

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     ZEIT+ BEFEHL

20489 xrdp      20   0   50252  22608   6376 S  13,3  0,3   0:30.07 xrdp

770 root      20   0  673752  86520  22408 S   6,7  1,0   2:13.83 Xorg

848 root      20   0  424304  26964  20852 S   6,7  0,3   0:00.25 Thunar

853 root      20   0  450584  37344  14604 S   6,7  0,4   0:02.29 xfdesktop

6751 root      20   0  629424  32736  20516 S   6,7  0,4   0:36.26 gnome-term+

```
1 root      20   0  225116   8280   6692 S   0,0  0,1   0:01.67 systemd
```

65 root      20   0  357976  86900  80612 S   0,0  1,0   0:16.92 systemd-jo+

176 root      20   0   42092   3068   2852 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.12 systemd-ud+

179 systemd+  20   0   71848   4532   4532 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.15 systemd-ne+

330 root      20   0   30044   2644   2544 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.10 cron

332 root      20   0   70564   5760   5360 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.16 systemd-lo+

343 message+  20   0   47848   4136   3632 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.06 dbus-daemon

352 syslog    20   0  189016   3936   3276 S   0,0  0,0   0:03.40 rsyslogd

359 root      20   0   72288   5884   5760 S   0,0  0,1   0:08.86 sshd

360 root      20   0  185980  18100  10304 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.09 unattended+

416 root      20   0  100968   1968   1848 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 saslauthd

419 root      20   0  100968    120      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 saslauthd

490 root      20   0   24176   2368   2364 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xinetd

492 root      20   0   35184    960    596 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 nginx

493 www-data  20   0   35652   4624   3940 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.14 nginx

494 www-data  20   0   35680   3232   2676 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.06 nginx

495 www-data  20   0   35552   1784   1364 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 nginx

497 www-data  20   0   35552   1112    812 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 nginx

552 root      20   0   67368   3660   3536 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.30 master

554 postfix   20   0   69468   4796   4672 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.08 qmgr

559 mysql     20   0 1689212  73488  13964 S   0,0  0,9   1:07.66 mysqld

563 root      20   0   59044   3392   2984 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp-sesman

596 xrdp      20   0   25272   2276   1680 S   0,0  0,0   0:05.05 xrdp

717 root      20   0  101544   7168   6184 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.24 sshd

736 root      20   0   76676   7756   6624 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.03 systemd

737 root      20   0  254740   1544     64 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 (sd-pam)

745 root      20   0   20328   3420   3068 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bash

768 root      20   0   59044   2532   2300 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp-sesman

769 root      20   0    4616    788    720 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 sh

773 root      20   0  124784   3772   2772 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.09 xrdp-chans+

786 root      20   0   47868   4444   3736 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.14 dbus-daemon

823 root      20   0   11292    316      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.37 ssh-agent

832 root      20   0  329420  13128  10708 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.22 xfce4-sess+

835 root      20   0  289556   6976   5540 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.01 polkitd

840 root      20   0   59384   4980   4320 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.05 xfconfd

844 root      20   0   92100   2500   2224 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 gpg-agent

846 root      20   0  181280  17356  13764 S   0,0  0,2   0:05.20 xfwm4

850 root      20   0  360612  20308  14660 S   0,0  0,2   0:03.02 xfce4-panel

851 root      20   0  375508  12840  10284 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.09 xfsettingsd

857 root      20   0  305772   7512   6468 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 upowerd

868 root      20   0  283772   5956   5088 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 gvfsd

881 root      20   0  168504  10764   8920 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.04 panel-6-sy+

882 root      20   0  178076  13156  10976 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.04 panel-2-ac+

883 root      20   0  371872   6352   5264 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.03 gvfs-udisk+

886 root      20   0  502440   7608   6244 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.07 udisksd

900 root      20   0  359904   6268   5188 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.04 gvfsd-trash

905 root      20   0  195984   4164   3764 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 gvfsd-meta+

6734 root      20   0  349140   5720   5148 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 at-spi-bus+

6739 root      20   0   47488   3592   3252 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 dbus-daemon

6741 root      20   0  220768   6044   5336 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.03 at-spi2-re+

6758 root      20   0   20328   3688   3140 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bash

6787 root      20   0   20328   3748   3200 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bash

6799 root      20   0 1819380 163300  12904 S   0,0  1,9   0:03.73 rasa

7370 root      20   0 3961496 379292  13276 S   0,0  4,5   0:17.57 rasa

7389 root      20   0   20328   3388   3008 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bash

7405 root      20   0   40616   3488   2932 S   0,0  0,0   2:44.63 top

13432 root      20   0   11608   3100   2856 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 mysql-work+

13445 root      20   0    4616    804    740 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 catchsegv

13447 root      20   0  930904  88816  45124 S   0,0  1,1   0:18.98 mysql-work+

13458 root      20   0   20328   3488   3104 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bash

20488 root      20   0   13008   2084   1952 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 agetty

20490 root      20   0   14680   2404   2272 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 agetty

20514 root      20   0  424284  27608  21488 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.30 Thunar

20848 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20856 postfix   20   0   69420   5148   4684 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 pickup

20868 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20886 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20889 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20898 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20935 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20948 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20953 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20956 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20977 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20980 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20997 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20998 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

20999 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

21044 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

21049 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

21078 root      20   0   72288   5732   5004 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 sshd

21081 sshd      20   0   72288    748      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 sshd

21092 xrdp      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 xrdp

21108 root      20   0   40476   3868   3352 R   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 top

ulimit-a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1545098
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62987
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info                  |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| 34 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results of top, htop and ulimit -a reports and from MySQL client login as root, SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Comment: Our investigation revealed, that most likley it was k3s that was eating up all resources. After uninstalling k3s the issue seems resolved. However, now we need to find a way to use k3s without it stopping the server :-).

Comment: If this URL is to the k3s you are using, are your running Enterprise version of SQL?

     https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/datastore/  

If you could post the few items requested May 7, we could do some sanity checks on current environment.

Comment: @Wilson - I have added the outputs.

Comment: Thank you.  You have 17 Zombies, with PID's in use, blocking potential new connections.   Do you have flexibility to use Skype TALK in English?  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.  We are in UTC -6 hrs.  800 KM south of Chicago, IL

Comment: This NGINX url indicates minimum hardware is 8GB RAM and 8 Cores.  
    https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-controller/technical-specs/